# Как выбрать основного пользователя Windows 10 для загрузки?

Tags: windows-10

Хочу чтобы в Windows 10 загружался всегда один пользователь, независимо от того какой из них работал последний, чтобы не менять на экране загрузки.

Answer (score 1):

**Отключение запроса пароля при входе в настройках учетных записей пользователей**

1. Нажмите клавиши Windows + R (где Windows — клавиша с эмблемой ОС) и
   введите netplwiz или control userpasswords2 затем нажмите Ок. Обе
   команды вызовут появление одного и того же окна настройки учетных
   записей.
2. Чтобы включить автоматический вход в Windows 10 без ввода
   пароля, выберите пользователя, для которого нужно убрать запрос
   пароля и снимите отметку с «Требовать ввод имени пользователя и
   пароля».

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Нажмите «Ок» или «Применить», после чего потребуется ввести
   текущий пароль и его подтверждение для выбранного пользователя
   (которого можно и поменять, просто введя другой логин). **Внимание**:
   если у вас используется учетная запись Майкрософт и метод не
   сработает, попробуйте снова, но в верхнем поле вместо имени
   пользователя укажите привязанный адрес электронной почты (E-mail).

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как убрать пароль при входе с помощью редактора реестра Windows 10**

Для начала, запустите редактор реестра Windows 10, для этого нажмите клавиши Windows + R, введите regedit и нажмите Enter.

Перейдите к разделу реестра

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для включения автоматического входа в систему для домена, учетной записи Microsoft или локальной учетной записи Windows 10, выполните следующие шаги:

1. Измените значение AutoAdminLogon (дважды кликните по этому значению
   справа) на 1.
2. Измените значение DefaultDomainName на имя домена или
   имя локального компьютера (можно посмотреть в свойствах «Этот
   компьютер»). Если этого значения нет, его можно создать (Правая
   кнопка мыши — Создать — Строковый параметр).
3. При необходимости,
   измените DefaultUserName на другой логин, либо оставьте текущего
   пользователя.
4. Создайте строковый параметр DefaultPassword и в
   качестве значения укажите пароль учетной записи.

После этого можно закрыть редактор реестра и перезагрузить компьютер — вход в систему под выбранным пользователем должен произойти без запроса логина и пароля.